# Swiper autoplay not working on vertical direction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js, react-swiper

Swiper autoplay is not working when I switch direction to vertical. It is working fine on default horizontal. My swiper have 4 slides and after sliding 1, the autoplay stucks.

Here is my swiper configuration:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `disableOnInteraction: false` ? If the autoplay stucks after interaction, e.g. clicks, disableOnInteraction may be the reason. https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-autoplay-disableOnInteraction

Comment: Yes I have tried disableOnInteraction and pauseOnMouseEnter both. But it doesnt solve the issue.